# Visibility of div by other elements amout

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have the following structure

```
<div class='some-group'>
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>   
</div>
<div class='button'>Click</div>
```

I want that 'button' will be displayed if 'some-group' have more that 2 children and hidden if less that 2.
Is this possible using css only?

Comment: No, it is not possible using CSS only.

Comment: Not with that HTML structure. If the button could be placed inside the .some-group parent element as well, then it might be possible using what has been dubbed [“Quantity Queries”](https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) in some way.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not possible by using css only, and I don't think it is the right approach. Any dynamic behaviour should be implemented by javascript, with CSS being purely a style rules container. You are violating the separation of concerns principle from my point of view.

Comment: This is a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I think mine is a valid answer. I wrote that it is not possible, and give an alternative option. Please let me know why you think mine is not an answer.

Comment: @JacopoLanzoni it may be an answer now after the edit, as you initially stated 'I don't think'...

Comment: It would be even better an answer if it actually explained what the JS should do.